# How do I apply a CSS @media only screen query to change display?

Tags: css, media-queries, display

I'm having trouble working with labels and input fields and being able to arrange them in a good looking and organized manner. I decided to put them in a div and use CSS grid. It works on my system's screen, but is far from responsive when the screen shrinks (becomes small like it would in a mobile device)

Now I want to use the `@media` query condition to change the `display` to `inline block` when the screen's width changes, but the media query I currently have is not doing anything.

Here is the related CSS:

```
.box-cons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  column-gap: 8%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1280){
  .box-cons {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is simple typographical error, use px in the device width definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I apologize for such an omission. it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1280px){
   .box-cons{
    display: block;
   }
  }
```

you forgot the px unit and your medie query is not working

Comment: Oh. sincerely apologize for using up resources for a simple typo error. Thank you so much